# Transferring data from Xbox 360 to Xbox One WITHOUT XBOX LIVE

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network

When I signed up for Xbox Live as requested by my son, I purchased it stupidly via my Microsoft account. I assumed that the Live benefits would apply to all the accounts on the Xbox. They don't. My son got an Xbox One and wants to transfer his game data from the Xbox 360, but since his account isn't linked to the Xbox Live account, he can't upload his data to the cloud (in order to then download it onto the Xbox One from the cloud).

I want to know if there's a way to transfer the Xbox Live membership to his account.

He suggested getting a one-month Xbox Live membership just on his account so that then he could do this transfer, but I'd like to find out if there's another way (there *has* to be another way) first.

Also, I've described the situation to the best of my understanding. If something doesn't make sense, I've gotten this information from an excited 12-year-old boy, so please ask me questions so that I can clarify them.

Comment: I asked because a Google search turned up someone asking the same thing here in 2011 (with an answer that is now irrelevant): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20066/how-do-i-change-an-xbox-gold-purchase-to-my-sons-profile

Comment: that ends the discussion, thanks for noticing me :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no other way, although you can get a free trial of Xbox Live so you may want to try that.

Comment: I think you're right, although to add insult to injury I think Microsoft require and actual Xbox Live Gold subscription rather than a trial one. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/transfer-data-from-xbox360-to-xbox-one/62e4148b-f64a-4cf4-bbc2-f24337d41cf7